# Frontier Flight 1929 3/21/24 DIVERTED - HELP FIND ATC RECORDING

Tags: air-traffic-control

My family was on frontier flight 1929 on 3/21/24 from PWM. It was diverted back to PWM within minutes of take off. I am trying to find the ATC recording for the reason why it was diverted. Can anyone help get this clip? been trying to find it on liveatc.net with no luck!

Comment: I'm curious what announcements were made to the passengers, both in flight and after landing. It's tough for the crew because besides being busy with the procedure, they have to try not to alarm the 99% of passengers who know nothing about airplanes other than what they watch on _Mayday!_  and will likely freak out if they hear there is engine trouble. From your question it sounds like no reason was given for returning, but surely they said something? Was it a vague "we need to go back and check something" type of announcement?

Answer (score 8):

It's on [liveatc's PWM "tower 2" feed](https://www.liveatc.net/search/?icao=pwm), [here's the specific file](https://archive.liveatc.net/kpwm/KPWM3-Twr-Mar-21-2024-1800Z.mp3). It took off and they were handed off to departure.

[Going over to that frequency](https://archive.liveatc.net/kpwm/KPWM3-App-Dep-Mar-21-2024-1800Z.mp3), they check in at 1500 feet and are cleared to 10k feet. They then call back in and say "we're gonna need to come back into Portland for a landing". They stated they were having surging on one of their engines. They said "no equipment necessary", so they weren't concerned at all.

Departure asked for their numbers, which implies that they may have called an emergency for the airplane. They listed passenger counts and fuel quantity, which is standard.

The plane then came back in and tower asked if they needed anything. They said "everything worked out".

Pretty standard stuff.

The plane, N334FR, hasn't been used since- though that was Thursday, today's Sunday, so maintenance may not even be looking at it yet.

Comment: For the record, the involved plane (N334FR) completed its first flight today, 9 days after the diverted flight.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part of the ATC recording is available [here](https://archive.liveatc.net/kpwm/KPWM2-App-Dep-Mar-21-2024-1800Z.mp3), at around a time stamp of 11:20. They were having some surging in one of the engines.